# Having trouble creating makefile for JAVA

Tags: java, ubuntu, makefile

I'd like to try and create a makefile for my project.  I am running this in linux not in windows, specifically ubuntu.

This is what my project directory looks like:

```
project_root
    /src
        A.java
        B.java
        C.java
        D.java
    /bin
       #this is where I'd like the .class files
    /include 
        A.jar
        B.jar
        C.jar
    makefile
    run.sh
```

And this is what my makefile looks like:

```
JC = javac
CLASSPATH = .:include/*
SRCPATH = ./src/
OUTDIR = ./bin/

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:
        $(JC) -cp $(CLASSPATH) $(OUTPATH) $*.java

CLASSES = \
        $(SRCPATH)A.java \
        $(SRCPATH)B.java \
        $(SRCPATH)C.java \
        $(SRCPATH)D.java 

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) $(SRCPATH)*.class
```

When I run make in the project directory I get this output:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `.java', needed by `javac'.  Stop.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why? This strikes me as a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/243725).

Comment: Does anyone really use make for java?  I've never known anyone to do so.  The standard Java build tools are ant, maven, gradle ... but make?  Leave that to the C guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have a TAB character as the first character in the line when you define your `.java.class` suffix rule.

In make, every recipe line *must* include an actual TAB character (not just spaces) as the first character in the line.  If the first character is not a real TAB, then it's not a recipe line.

The reason you don't get a syntax error is because your line looks like a rule, due to the colon in the `CLASSPATH`; it looks like this:

```
javac -cp .:include/* ./bin/ .java
```

(`$*` expands to nothing here) which is parsed by make to be defining three targets, `javac`, `-cp`, and `.`, each of which depends on `include/*`, `./bin/`, and `.java`.

Hence your error message.